# JSON Not Implicitly Converted to RequestBody Object by Jackson Dependancy On Post Request In Spring Mvc?

Tags: hibernate, rest, maven, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I have been trying to make a Post Request To Insert data via `UserTransaction Model` for the users which do exists in `UserModel` class. It works until I insert the data seperately in Users Table via request handler method `public String addUser(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> userJson)` using `UserModel` class in LoginForm Controller.

But, The problem is when I try to insert data which is relational. It doesnt work and result is not even called to the controller RequestHandler method
 `public void doTransaction(@RequestBody usertransaction tr)` as implicit conversion of JSON received from jsp by jackson dependency to usertransaction tr object doesnt seems to be happening.

Transaction Jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fastcdn.org/Animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="post"   id="form" style="">














        <table cellspacing="15" style="">
            <tr>
                <th><label>UserId </label></th>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="userId" name="userId" required
                    placeholder="" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th><label>transactionAmount</label></th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="transactionAmount"
                    name="transactionAmount" required placeholder="transactionAmount"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><label>From</label></th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="from" name="from" required
                    placeholder="from"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th><label>To</label></th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="to" name="to" required
                    placeholder="to"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th><label>transactionDate</label></th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="transactionDate"
                    name="transactionDate" required placeholder="transactionDate"></td>

            </tr>


            <tr>
                <th><label>PaymentMode</label></th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="PaymentMode" name="PaymentMode"
                    required placeholder="PaymentMode"></td>

            </tr>



            <tr>
                <th><label> CurrentBalance</label></th>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id=" CurrentBalance" name="CurrentBalance"
                    required placeholder=" CurrentBalance"></td>

            </tr>














            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th><button class="btn btn-primary " id="submit">Register</button>
                </tr>



            </tfoot>






        </table>

    </form>
        <script>
    $("#submit")
    .click(
            function(e) {
//alert('hello');
                var loginForm = $('#form').serializeArray();

                var loginFormObject = {};

                $.each(loginForm, function(i, v) {
                    loginFormObject[v.name] = v.value;
                });
                var loginFormObject = {};
                $.each(loginForm, function(i, v) {
                    loginFormObject[v.name] = v.value;
                });
            alert("hello");
            alert(JSON.stringify(loginFormObject));

                $
                        .ajax({
                            url : "userTransaction.obj",
                            type : "POST",
                            data : JSON.stringify(loginFormObject),
                            contentType : 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                            dataType : "text",
                            success : function(res) {

                                alert(res);

                            }
                        });
                e.preventDefault();

            });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginController Class

```
package com.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.model.LoginModel;
import com.model.usertransaction;
import com.service.LoginService;

@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
public class LoginForm {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginservice;
    /*
     * @RequestMapping(value="users", method=RequestMethod.POST
     * ,headers="Accept=*", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
     * public ResponseEntity<LoginModel> addUser(@RequestBody LoginModel users1)
     * { System.out.println("calllleddd");
     * this.loginservice.insertDetails(users1);
     * 
     * return new ResponseEntity<LoginModel>(users1,HttpStatus.OK); }
     */

    @Autowired
    LoginService ls;

    @RequestMapping(value = "TransactionPortal")
    public ModelAndView getTransactionPage() {
        // System.out.println("called");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("Transaction");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "userTransaction", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public void doTransaction(@RequestBody usertransaction tr) {
        System.out.println("called for registration.....");

        this.ls.doTransaction(tr);

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "users", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public String addUser(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> userJson) {
        String message = "";
        System.out.println("calllleddd");
        if (this.loginservice.createUser(userJson) == true) {
            message = "Congrats! The credentials have been registered";
        } else {
            message = "The credentials already exists";

        }

        return message;
    }









}
```

UserTransaction Model Class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ManyToAny;
import org.hibernate.engine.Cascade;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usertransaction")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class usertransaction implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private UserModel user;

    public int getUserId() {
        return user.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userid) {
        user.userId = userid;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "transactionId")
    private int transactionId;
    @Column(name = "transactionAmount")
    private String transactionAmount;
    @Column(name = "from")
    private String from;

    @Column(name = "to")
    private String to;

    @Column(name = "transactionDate")
    private String transactionDate;

    @Column(name = "PaymentMode")
    private String PaymentMode;

    @Column(name = "CurrentBalance")
    private String CurrentBalance;

    public int getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;

    }

    public void setTransactionId(int transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }

    public String getTransactionAmount() {
        return transactionAmount;
    }

    public void setTransactionAmount(String transactionAmount) {
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getTransactionDate() {
        return transactionDate;
    }

    public void setTransactionDate(String transactionDate) {
        this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
    }

    public String getPaymentMode() {
        return PaymentMode;
    }

    public void setPaymentMode(String paymentMode) {
        PaymentMode = paymentMode;
    }

    public String getCurrentBalance() {
        return CurrentBalance;
    }

    public void setCurrentBalance(String currentBalance) {
        CurrentBalance = currentBalance;
    }

}
```

UserModel Class

```
package com.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;




    @Entity
    @Table(name="users")
    public class UserModel {


        @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
        Set<usertransaction> s=new HashSet<usertransaction>();


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="userId")
        public int userId;
        @Column(name="userName")
        private String userName;
        @Column(name="userDescription")
        private String userDescription;
        @Column(name="status")
        private String status;
        @Column(name="statusCode")
        private String statusCode;
        @Column(name="statusDescription")
        private String statusDescription;
        @Column(name="userSince") 
        private String userSince;
        @Column(name="PIN") 
        private String PIN;
        public int getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }
        public void setUserId(int userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }
        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }
        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }
        public String getUserDescription() {
            return userDescription;
        }
        public void setUserDescription(String userDescription) {
            this.userDescription = userDescription;
        }
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
        public String getStatusCode() {
            return statusCode;
        }
        public void setStatusCode(String string) {
            this.statusCode = string;
        }
        public String getStatusDescription() {
            return statusDescription;
        }
        public void setStatusDescription(String statusDescription) {
            this.statusDescription = statusDescription;
        }
        public String getUserSince() {
            return userSince;
        }
        public void setUserSince(String userSince) {
            this.userSince = userSince;
        }
        public String getPIN() {
            return PIN;
        }
        public void setPIN(String pIN) {
            PIN = pIN;
        }
        public String getErrorDescription() {
            return errorDescription;
        }
        public void setErrorDescription(String errorDescription) {
            this.errorDescription = errorDescription;
        }
        @Column(name="errorDescription")
        private String errorDescription;


    }
```

For reference check below the first image shows the bad request and controller doesnt get called but when I remove the 
@RequestBody it works shown in the second image

[image][image]

Comment: can i please get an answer to this as I am stuck with this so as to proceed with my project?

Comment: Is this ajax url `url : "userTransaction.obj"`, correct? Did you tried open the console and track the request? What response you are getting?

Comment: That is what the error is it gives bad request error as the implicit conversion is not working ajax request  works when I remove that @RequestBody since the  json object sent via ajax is not being converted to a Model usertransaction hence the error

Comment: And you dont have any error log? This seems to be problem `public void setUserId(int userid) {
        user.userId = userid;
    }` When you are serializing json `user` is null, so this should throw NPE

Comment: if that was the case i would have got error at the server console at thr backend

Comment: If server didnt log any error, it doesnt mean that there is none, since you are getting 500 response status. Check your logging settings

Comment: On the AJAX post should the you have dataType : "text", should that not be dataType:       'json'

Comment: @mkane check the content type

Comment: Can you rename class `usertransaction` to `UserTransaction`? Ignoring Java Naming conventions could be a problem.

Comment: ok but thats a wild guess though i hope you agree on that

Comment: I could not see exact error message on the console

Comment: there is no error message indeed on server console. It gives error on browsers console when the conversion of Json passed via ajax to controller doesnt happen @RequestBody takes input as json object received from ajax and implicitely converts to usertransaction object of model